# Possible to define a parameter as string OR array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, parameters

Is there a way I could write a php function that could contain a parameter which could be either a string or an array?

Comment: Function parameters in PHP are typeless by default / currently. You may want to show your specific code and explain the specific issue you've run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a loosely typed language, thus your parameters can be any type. You can also write PHP docblock comments if you want to specify the type(s) the function is expecting. [phpdoc](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/glossary.html#term-structural-elements) is a good resource. Note, though, that docblock comments are **comments** and do not affect the code

```
/**
* @param string|array $my_variable
*/
function myFunction($my_variable){
    if(is_string($my_variable)){
        //Do something
    }
    if(is_array($my_variable)){
        //Do something
    }
}
```